# R proc.time() output interpretation

Tags: r

In RGui terminal, I just typed

```
ptm = proc.time()
ptm
```

The result is like

```
user  system elapsed 
0.21    0.87   50.32
```

So, it takes 50.32 **seconds**? I did nothing. What is the time unit for `elapsed` ?

Many thanks if someone can help it or forward this to some expert.

Answer (score 1):

The time unit of all these three numbers is second.

`elapsed` is the time counted from the RGui terminal session starts. So if we type the code again, it can be found the `elapsed` time will always grow larger, it is accumulative.